# Observer: Use of die language construct is discouraged

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento-2.0, marketplace

I have submitted one module in the Magento Marketplace. I got error:

> "Use of die language construct is discouraged".

Module is written by another programmer, I don't know how to change it to fix the problem.

I tried to find solution. Standard recommendation is using `setBody()`. But the Observer class does not have this method.

Code of invalid class:

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject as Object;

class RenderPopup implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
    }


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        if ($this->_request->getParam('quickview')) {
            if ($observer->getEvent()->getElementName() == 'main') {
                print_r($observer->getEvent()->getTransport()->getData('output')); 
                die;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is totally useless, the only reason I can see an usage is for debugging purpose.

My suggestion:

- Back it up
- Delete it
- Remove the corresponding entries in the `events.xml` files of your module

Comment: Don't you have any other solution? Your solution like a hack.

Comment: @Oborotenby did you read my answer ? The code you posted DOES NOT DO anything. It's totally useless so you can get rid of the file itself.

Comment: I understood it. But if the code is useful, what would I need to print some text?

Comment: @Oborotenby what event does it observe ?

Comment: It does not observe anything in this module. But it can be a useful observer theoreticaly.

Comment: @Oborotenby well it depends on the event you're observing. But usually you either call `return $this;` or you redirect.

Answer (score 0):

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject as Object;

class RenderPopup implements ObserverInterface
{
protected $_request;

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context
) {
    $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
}


public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    if ($this->_request->getParam('quickview')) {
        if ($observer->getEvent()->getElementName() == 'main') {
            print_r($observer->getEvent()->getTransport()->getData('output')); 
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

}